# Using Ctrl-Alt-F1

Tags: shortcut-keys

I have a program, a metaverse viewer (any of the graphic ones apply here) and it uses <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> for a UI function. But I can't get that key combination to actually do anything.

I've disabled VT switching in xorg.conf, so now it doesn't switch to a VT, but it seems <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> doesn't generate anything, or it's suppressed somewhere else. I'm just not sure where else to look.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

Launch *Keyboard Layout* and choose Options...:

[image]

Make sure the following checkbox is selected:

[image]