# No Ctrl-Alt-F1-F6 on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: shortcut-keys, 20.04

Since I installed Ubuntu 20.04 on my PC I can not get <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> to <kbd>F6</kbd> working. Here are my config:

- OS: Ubuntu x86_64 (5.4.0-29-generic)
- Motherboard: msi B450M MORTAR MAX, MS-7B89 1.0, 32 GB RAM
- CPU: AMD Ryzen 5 3600 (12) @ 3.600GHz
- GPU: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1050 Ti
- GPU Driver: NVIDIA 440.64
- Resolution: 2560x1440 @ 59.95Hz

I have tried different solutions published here, with no success:

- [How to launch GUI app in Ctrl+Alt+F7 from tty Ctrl+Alt+F1-F6](https://askubuntu.com/questions/541438/how-to-launch-gui-app-in-ctrlaltf7-from-tty-ctrlaltf1-f6)
- [Using Ctrl-Alt-F1](https://askubuntu.com/questions/115709/using-ctrl-alt-f1)
- [Cannot do Ctrl+Alt+F1 after login](https://askubuntu.com/questions/858647/cannot-do-ctrlaltf1-after-login)
- [Enable Ctrl+Alt+F1 Virtual Consoles in GNOME Ubuntu 17.04+](https://askubuntu.com/questions/911560/enable-ctrlaltf1-virtual-consoles-in-gnome-ubuntu-17-04)

Does anyone have a solution?

Comment: The Hint "Cannot do Ctrl+Alt+F1 after login" is not useful.

Comment: Hey Guys. The problem is solved. It is the Keyboard (Microsoft Wireless ComfordKeyboard 5000). With a wired Keyboard the Keystorkes are working... *lol*

Comment: It works also with the Microsoft Wireless ComfordKeyboard 5000. The F-LOCK Key was activated ]:-)

Comment: Please don't put [SOLVED] in the question title in this site. Write an answer to the question by clicking on **Answer Your Own Question** button below and provide a detailed solution. If the problem faulty keyboard, or otherwise not related to Ubuntu, then please delete the question. Deleting the question will reduce the work of close vote reviewers and site admins, who will eventually delete the question.